# Updating model in Entity Framework removes timeout

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

In my database model (`.edmx` file -> `mySource.Context.tt` -> `mySource.Context.cs`) I have set timeout to a certain value, but when I update my model (update from DB) it removes my `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;` entry, because this file is automatically populated.

Is there a way every time I update my entity model that it puts the aforementioned timeout code back in?

I'm considering creating a unit test to fail when this code is removed, but I would rather be a bit more proactive and prevent it from occurring.

```
public myEntities() : base("name=myEntities")
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;     
    // Set timeout to 5 minutes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the template `mySource.Context.tt` to include this line in the constructor. When you run the update it basically runs the t4template to generate the `mySource.Context.cs` file.

Here's the snippet which will help you identifying the section where to update. Open your mySource.Context.tt. Look for below snippet and add the line of code for timeout exactly where I placed in below snippet.

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
       // Timeout setting
       ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300; 
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.Context.cs` contains a partial class. Create a file and copy these lines from your `.Context.cs` (the names may be different):

```
namespace Whatever
public partial class myEntities : DbContext
{
}
```

then simply add the line to set the timeout. Your file will not be overwritten:

```
    public partial class myEntities : DbContext
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }
```

Comment: This is another way to do it. Deserve a +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the command timeout in the connection string; simply add "....;CommandTimeout=300;..." to the connection string. I would not necessarily hard-code it in EF.